# Allow UIImagePickerController to select a photo from Saved Photos, but also access full Photo Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on an app that allows the user to upload an image. When choosing an image from their library, I want it to initially load the **Camera Roll (Saved Photos)**, but also provide a "back" button to access the rest of their **Photo Library** (i.e. other albums).

Here's my code:

```
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
      UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
      imagePicker.delegate = self;
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
      [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
  }
  else {
      UIAlertView *alert;
      alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                         message:@"This device doesn't support photo libraries."
                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
  }
```

This starts off on the full Photo Library screen, which allows users to select any image from any album, but requires one more tap to get into camera roll, then over to the next upload screen.

If I switch — `imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;` then it starts off in the camera roll, but doesn't allow access to the other albums.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: Both iPhone and iPad, the current code works the same on both I think.

Comment: Thanks @iPatel! I'd like to use a native solution if possible, but if not I'll check that out.